# Android ViewModel - how to force recreation on certain configuration changes

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-components

[ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)'s purpose is to retain data on life cycle events and configuration changes.

But for certain configuration changes, like **locale change**, I would like to get a fresh instance of viewModel. How can I force recreation?

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // How to get new instance on locale change?
        var viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)
        .get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can achieve that by creating custom `ViewModelFactory` object and make condition there to whether create new obj or use existing from there.

Comment: [ViewModelProvider.Factory.html#create(java.lang.Class<T>)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.Factory.html#create(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) is not called on language change or any other configuration change.

Comment: I don't think you can. Best thing you can do is create your own `reset()` function on your ViewModel type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Answering my own question :)*

I had the chance to speak with Yigit Boyar (lead for Architecture Components) on Google I/O 2019.
He confirmed **it's intentionally not possible** to force recreation on ViewModel. The right solution is to observe changes and act on them.

Comment: So you basically need to add a reset method to each viewmodel, that should be resettable. Do you know, why it's intentionally not possible?